# Why does when I use different name for get api, it doesn't work? ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

In my server-side.js, I have 3 get api for 3 different model

```
//Get user for Appointment Request
app.get("/getAppointmentDetails", async(req,res) => {
    
  await AppRequest.find({})
      .then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       console.log('error: ', error)
      });
    });
    
//Get user for Appointment Details
app.get("/getAppointmentDetail", async(req,res) => {
    
      await AppDetails.find({})
          .then((data) => {
            res.json(data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
           console.log('error: ', error)
          });
        });

//Get details for Receipts
app.get("/getAppointmentReceipt", async(req,res) => {
    
  await ReceiptDetails.find({})
      .then((data) => {
        res.json(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
       console.log('error: ', error)
      });
    });
```

**/getAppointmentDetails** and **/getAppointmentDetail** is retrieving data but **/getAppointmentReceipt** is retrieving random html response.

This is the response I get from **/getAppointmentReceipt**

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"/><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"/><meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app"/><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/logo192.png"/><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/><title>Rimorin Dental Clinic</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css"><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-uWxY/CJNBR+1zjPWmfnSnVxwRheevXITnMqoEIeG1LJrdI0GlVs/9cVSyPYXdcSF" crossorigin="anonymous"><link href="/static/css/19.bb342c48.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"><link href="/static/css/main.ba1b2f62.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kQtW33rZJAHjgefvhyyzcGF3C5TFyBQBA13V1RKPf4uH+bwyzQxZ6CmMZHmNBEfJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script>!function(d){function e(e){for(var t,r,n=e[0],a=e[1],f=e[2],c=0,o=[];c<n.length;c++)r=n[c],s[r]&&o.push(s[r][0]),s[r]=0;for(t in a)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,t)&&(d[t]=a[t]);for(p&&p(e);o.length;)o.shift()();return i.push.apply(i,f||[]),u()}function u(){for(var e,t=0;t<i.length;t++){for(var r=i[t],n=!0,a=1;a<r.length;a++){var f=r[a];0!==s[f]&&(n=!1)}n&&(i.splice(t--,1),e=b(b.s=r[0]))}return e}var r={},l={18:0},s={18:0},i=[];function b(e){if(r[e])return r[e].exports;var t=r[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return d[e].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,b),t.l=!0,t.exports}b.e=function(i){var e=[];l[i]?e.push(l[i]):0!==l[i]&&{1:1,4:1,5:1,6:1,7:1,8:1,9:1,10:1,11:1,12:1,13:1,14:1,15:1,20:1,21:1,22:1,23:1,25:1,26:1,27:1,28:1,29:1,30:1,31:1,32:1,33:1,34:1,35:1}[i]&&e.push(l[i]=new Promise(function(e,n){for(var t="static/css/"+({}[i]||i)+"."+{0:"31d6cfe0",1:"9da47678",2:"31d6cfe0",3:"31d6cfe0",4:"d56f1ee6",5:"280e91df",6:"f8148f9a",7:"3d7cfabe",8:"c13c737f",9:"c13c737f",10:"c13c737f",11:"c13c737f",12:"3d7cfabe",13:"f8148f9a",14:"d92adf1b",15:"ec2d6915",16:"31d6cfe0",20:"42ba9a0c",21:"3d7cfabe",22:"3d7cfabe",23:"f8bd023e",24:"31d6cfe0",25:"f49f5811",26:"3d7cfabe",27:"5d8efac8",28:"f8148f9a",29:"0f6e55cd",30:"f8db929a",31:"d92adf1b",32:"ec2d6915",33:"0f6e55cd",34:"667fb273",35:"78c11edf",36:"31d6cfe0",37:"31d6cfe0",38:"31d6cfe0",39:"31d6cfe0",40:"31d6cfe0",41:"31d6cfe0"}[i]+".chunk.css",a=b.p+t,r=document.getElementsByTagName("link"),f=0;f<r.length;f++){var c=(d=r[f]).getAttribute("data-href")||d.getAttribute("href");if("stylesheet"===d.rel&&(c===t||c===a))return e()}var o=document.getElementsByTagName("style");for(f=0;f<o.length;f++){var d;if((c=(d=o[f]).getAttribute("data-href"))===t||c===a)return e()}var u=document.createElement("link");u.rel="stylesheet",u.type="text/css",u.onload=e,u.onerror=function(e){var t=e&&e.target&&e.target.src||a,r=new Error("Loading CSS chunk "+i+" failed.\n("+t+")");r.request=t,delete l[i],u.parentNode.removeChild(u),n(r)},u.href=a,document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(u)}).then(function(){l[i]=0}));var r=s[i];if(0!==r)if(r)e.push(r[2]);else{var t=new Promise(function(e,t){r=s[i]=[e,t]});e.push(r[2]=t);var n,f=document.createElement("script");f.charset="utf-8",f.timeout=120,b.nc&&f.setAttribute("nonce",b.nc),f.src=b.p+"static/js/"+({}[i]||i)+"."+{0:"153d27ad",1:"3dec8936",2:"84cfbf61",3:"ab6c8b81",4:"747be47e",5:"f10d57db",6:"20379919",7:"bf781eca",8:"6685209f",9:"54a793fd",10:"adf5adfd",11:"c5a6a7f6",12:"89ab7eea",13:"71d175f2",14:"57472d90",15:"ec65f994",16:"4fb2db86",20:"d0a5e996",21:"ded92a52",22:"fccc6465",23:"1372ca51",24:"92f3500f",25:"42dfdbb0",26:"d86c482a",27:"9aa67369",28:"2c9d411c",29:"ca024051",30:"17ec4e30",31:"f1a85355",32:"9b873c6c",33:"1a77e064",34:"dca26e1a",35:"90cb04ed",36:"0eb7fe77",37:"6496da55",38:"0bc1a5d3",39:"d4739f35",40:"09a9f81e",41:"e4ffc82b"}[i]+".chunk.js",n=function(e){f.onerror=f.onload=null,clearTimeout(c);var t=s[i];if(0!==t){if(t){var r=e&&("load"===e.type?"missing":e.type),n=e&&e.target&&e.target.src,a=new Error("Loading chunk "+i+" failed.\n("+r+": "+n+")");a.type=r,a.request=n,t[1](a)}s[i]=void 0}};var c=setTimeout(function(){n({type:"timeout",target:f})},12e4);f.onerror=f.onload=n,document.head.appendChild(f)}return Promise.all(e)},b.m=d,b.c=r,b.d=function(e,t,r){b.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},b.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},b.t=function(t,e){if(1&e&&(t=b(t)),8&e)return t;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof t&&t&&t.__esModule)return t;var r=Object.create(null);if(b.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:t}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof t)for(var n in t)b.d(r,n,function(e){return t[e]}.bind(null,n));return r},b.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return b.d(t,"a",t),t},b.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},b.p="/",b.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var t=window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[],n=t.push.bind(t);t.push=e,t=t.slice();for(var a=0;a<t.length;a++)e(t[a]);var p=n;u()}([])</script><script src="/static/js/19.4ffc5a4f.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.68f82c7a.chunk.js"></script></body></html> this is the response
```

but when I change the **/getAppointmentDetails**'s model from **AppRequest** to **ReceiptDetails**

It retrieves the data that I need. Is there a GET naming convention rule?

Comment: It looks like your web server is configured to return html on the `/` route. Most likely you have a spelling error and your router is falling back to `/` for unmatched routes. You will have to show your entire express config for us to know.